# Impala Query Hangs after finished in Hue

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, impala, cloudera-cdh, hue

I use Hue as an interface to run Impala queries. Sometimes
queries seem to have finished but the results are not displayed at Hue. The logs through Hue show that all tasks are completed but it stacks at loading as shown in the next picture:

[image]

Opening a JDBC connection to Impala and running the some query seems to be immune to this problem so I guess it is a Hue issue. Is there a way to find the actual cause for this problem and to fix it?